# C# projects importing a props file ignores output type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, csproj

I have a solution with multiple projects. Most are libraries except for two that are EXE projects.

I wanted to share assembly information in a file.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <BaseNamespace>Shared.Namespace</BaseNamespace>
        <Company>My company</Company>
        <Authors>Author's name</Authors>
        <Copyright>$(Company)</Copyright>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <RootNamespace>$(BaseNamespace).$(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_"))</RootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

That I import in the projects using `<Import Project="..\ProjectsCommon.props" />`. The properties are well propagated and can be overridden, except for `OutputType`.

The EXE projects are considered as Library ones. If I set the output type in the props file to EXE, then all projects are compiled as EXE (which creates errors due to missing Main).

Here is the real project commit that I am talking about:
https://github.com/CyberInternauts/CmdStarter/commit/5ef693de1e2fd220f820ea4439bcb33a949fca0b

Only two things to look:

- The `.props` file
- The `.Demo.csproj` file

Any ideas?

Comment: Not reproducible, I put `Library` in the props file and `Exe` in the project file, an exe file was built. If I commented out `Exe`, only a dll file was built. My environment: Visual Studio 17.5.5 .Net 7.0 ... BTW `Import` should be put at the beginning of the project file.

Comment: @shingo It is right after the opening `<Project...>` tag. I'll do other tests later. I'll inform you then.

Comment: @shingo I added a commit to the project where it is related. Using this files structure, it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `Sdk` attribute on the project element, it will add [an implicit import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk?view=vs-2022), this results in a conflict to the import in the csproj file.

Removing it from the .props file will solve your problem.

```xml
<Project>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <BaseNamespace>Shared.Namespace</BaseNamespace>
        <Company>My company</Company>
        <Authors>Author's name</Authors>
        <Copyright>$(Company)</Copyright>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <RootNamespace>$(BaseNamespace).$(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_"))</RootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Weirdly, I modified the file and test... not working. I restarted VS and I saw the file was not modified. This time, it worked. Thank you!